# How to prevent log out users when changing JWT secret?

Tags: jwt

I am using a JWT token implementation of this https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/

I need to update the secret key and is there a way to update it without logging out every user? I presume it's not possible to reuse the old token once my secret key is changed. So all my users will be logged off and need to log in again. Is there any way to go around this?

If not, if for security reason, I need to update the secret monthly, that will be pretty troublesome to ask my user to re-login monthly.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to implement some kind of secret key versioning. When a user tries to authenticate he will test the latest version in priority to older which were deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your keys it's correct to invalidate all the tokens signed with the old ones as they are to be considered expired.

It's a good practice to let the token expire as well after a certain amount of time. Usually you implement a mechanism based on two tokens, `access_token` with an expiration of 1h (usually) and a `refresh_token` with a longer expiration (usually 24h). The second one is used to renew the first one. When the second one expires, the user has to be considered logged out.

What you need is to implement a refresh token mechanism. You can implement it from scratch, for learning purposes, or you could just implement OAuth 2.0 protocol, since it's a flow that it already supports. There are lots of libraries both for server side and client side implementations

https://oauth.net/